# How to create SortedDictionary+ValueCollection type?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create object with the following type:

> System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2+ValueCollection

When I run the fllwing command:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(SortedDictionary<string, object>));
```

I am getting the following output:

> System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2

How can I create an object that

> typeof(TheType) == System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2 **+ValueCollection**

Comment: A better question is why you think you need this. Taking any kind of dependency on this type is going to produce very fragile code and it's likely completely unnecessary. One very important gotcha to consider is that you can't create instances of this type that are separate from a `SortedDictionary`, as it's only meant to encapsulate a view.

Answer (score 0):

The [SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.valuecollection?view=net-6.0) is a nested class. `SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` acts like a namespace for this `ValueCollection`:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(typeof(SortedDictionary<string, object>.ValueCollection));

sortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, object>();
var valueCollection =
    new SortedDictionary<string, object>.ValueCollection(sortedDictionary);
```

However the `SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` automatically creates such a `ValueCollection` internally. So, you will not need to create it yourself. It is returned by the `Values` property of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

the "typeof(SortedDictionary<string, object>)" will return the path in the assembly where the SortedDictionary é created

you can

```
SortedDictionary.Add("test", new object[]);
```

do a `foreach` in it or get the values in it

"typeof(TheType) == System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2 +ValueCollection"

if you want to compare you can use

```
typeof(TheType) == typeof(SortedDictionary.key)
typeof(TheType) == typeof(SortedDictionary.value)
```